# Error with encoding with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django, scrapy

I am using scrapy and django. While cleaning the data I use this:

```
html = re.sub(r'(™|®|©|&trade;|&reg;|&copy;|&#8482;|&#174;|&#169;)', '',html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Running in normal python shell is fine. However every time I try to run this with scrapy crawl, I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file
>   /somefile/
>   on line 105, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Can someone please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to extract your search string out and declare it a unicode string explicitly?  `mystring=u'regexp|regexp'` and using that in the substring matching?

Answer (score 0):

I declared encoding in my file by:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Make sure to put them on the first line of the file. 
This seemed to fix my problem.

Thank You Everyone!

Comment: Important: This just sets the encoding for the code, not for files you read.